# Best way to show a loading/progress indicator?

Tags: android, android-spinner

What is the best way to show a loading spinner while the app is waiting for a response from the server?

Can this be done programmatically? So that I don't have to add the load spinner in the xml file?

Answer (score 312, accepted):

**[ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) is deprecated from Android Oreo. Use [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) instead**

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setTitle("Loading");
progress.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
progress.setCancelable(false); // disable dismiss by tapping outside of the dialog
progress.show();
// To dismiss the dialog
progress.dismiss();
```

**OR**

```
ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Wait while loading...");
```

[Read more here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

By the way, **Spinner** has a different meaning in Android. (It's like the select dropdown in HTML)

Comment: From the Android Developer website: STYLE_SPINNER Creates a ProgressDialog with a circular, spinning progress bar.

Comment: This works, but when I tested this, I could dismiss the dialog by touching the screen outside of it or pressing the *Back* button. I fixed this by adding a call to `progress.setCancelable(false);`.

Comment: Thanks for the bottom comment. I was going crazy because I was trying to get 'spinner' to work for an hour.

Comment: superb, now I can use progress dialog

Comment: `ProgressDialog` was deprecated in Android O
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Comment: Progress dialogs are bad UX in general. Avoid them.

Comment: ProgressDialog is now deprecated and should be avoided.

Comment: @IvanSemkin Any suggestions on alternatives to be used instead?

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan as written in documentation:    
_ProgressDialog is a modal dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the app. Instead of using this class, you should use a progress indicator like ProgressBar, which can be embedded in your app's UI. Alternatively, you can use a notification to inform the user of the task's progress._
  
Sometimes I use also a SwipeRefreshLayout that shows a loading indicator and could be useful also to refresh in case of network failure. It can be activated/deactivated programmatically, but you need to insert it in layout xml.

Comment: @leodev Good points. However I am looking for a solution that doesn't  clutter my layout xml, and notifications is a different thing altogether.

Comment: anything in android that was once easy and quick to implement has been deprecated as a general rule. if it makes life easy, it's been deprecated.

Answer (score 29):

ProgressDialog has become deprecated since API Level 26
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

I include a ProgressBar in my layout

```
   <ProgressBar
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_cyclic"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp" />
```

and change its visibility to .GONE | .VISIBLE depending on the use case.

```
    progressBar_cyclic.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: Not sure, but does the progressBar run always in background(just hidden from the UI) after making it invisible?

Comment: @Shambhu if you set it to `View.GONE`, it doesn't render in UI at all and has no negative effect to performance. `View.INVISIBLE` is like making it transparent, but it's in UI thus worse for performance.

Answer (score 16):

Use [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

```
ProgressDialog.show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message);
```

[image]

However this is considered as an anti pattern today (2013): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I

Comment: @artworkadシ So what aspect of this is considered bad -- is the accepted answer an example of the same anti-pattern? And what is recommended to do instead? Linking to a offsite video about multiple UX issues does not really improve this answer.

Comment: `ProgressDialog` was deprecated in Android O
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 11):

Actually if you are waiting for response from a server it **should** be done programatically. You may create a progress dialog and dismiss it, but then again that is not "the android way".

Currently the recommended method is to use a **DialogFragment** :

```
public class MySpinnerDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public MySpinnerDialog() {
        // use empty constructors. If something is needed use onCreate's
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        _dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        this.setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, getTheme()); // You can use styles or inflate a view
        _dialog.setMessage("Spinning.."); // set your messages if not inflated from XML

        _dialog.setCancelable(false);  

        return _dialog;
    }
}
```

Then in your activity you set your Fragment manager and **show** the dialog once the wait for the server started:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
MySpinnerDialog myInstance = new MySpinnerDialog();
}
myInstance.show(fm, "some_tag");
```

Once your server has responded complete you will dismiss it:

```
myInstance.dismiss()
```

Remember that the progressdialog is a spinner or a progressbar depending on the attributes, read more on the [api guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: ProgressDialog.show(Context context, CharSequence title, CharSequence message);
Passing title parameter as empty string removes the title:

ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading..");

Comment: Fine example, though it was still possible for me to use the back button. I think it is because of your variable dlgAlert (and where is that coming from btw? :)).

Anyway - since you are extending dialogfragment, you can just call setCancelable(false) and it will work.

Comment: Committing fragment transactions at an indeterministic time when the server returns a response does not seem to be fool-proof. For example, when the response comes back, the activity that hosts the fragment may be in the wrong state. Any solution?

Comment: Make sure you're importing android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment and not android.app.DialogFragment, or you can't use getSupportFragmentManager (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514338/cannot-resolve-method-showandroid-support-v4-app-fragmentmanager-java-lang-st)

Comment: `ProgressDialog` was deprecated in Android O
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 6):

This is how I did this so that only one progress dialog can be open at a time. Based off of the answer from Suraj Bajaj

```
private ProgressDialog progress;



public void showLoadingDialog() {

    if (progress == null) {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setTitle(getString(R.string.loading_title));
        progress.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading_message));
    }
    progress.show();
}

public void dismissLoadingDialog() {

    if (progress != null && progress.isShowing()) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I also had to use

```
protected void onResume() {
    dismissLoadingDialog();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: `ProgressDialog` was deprecated in Android O
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the one and only version of "how to create a progress dialog because our loved ProgressDialog is deprecated" in Java:

Note: Used with Android 33.

```
    private AlertDialog progressAlertDialog = createProgressDialog(currentActivity / this);

    private AlertDialog createProgressDialog(AppCompatActivity currentActivity) {
        LinearLayout vLayout = new LinearLayout(currentActivity);
        vLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        vLayout.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
        vLayout.addView(new ProgressBar(currentActivity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge));

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setView(vLayout)
                .create();
    }

    public void displayProgressDialog() {
        if (!progressAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressAlertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public void hideProgressDialog() {
        progressAlertDialog.dismiss();
    }
```