# Android show a progress dialog before asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Such a simple thing but I'm having a huge problem with it.

**EDIT: I want my ProgressDialog to run while other classes are running - NOT be called within an asyncTask, as there are multiple asyncTasks being called.**

My main activity (index) calls another class, aTask, which calls an AsyncTask to grab some data from Yelp. When aTask returns the data, index starts a new activity.

I want index to show a progress dialog while aTask is running. So I use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842387/1851509) to put a progress dialog in index.

However, the progress bar is only shown after aTask finishes, which completely defeats the purpose.

Here is the code:

```
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProgressDialog.show(IndexActivity.this, "Loading", "Wait while loading...");
            ATask at = new ATask(preferencesMap, IndexActivity.this);

            final ArrayList<Business> locations = at.getLocations();

            Intent intent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, BTask.class);
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DIRECTIONS_STEPS", locations);
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MAP_LOCATIONS", locations);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is `at.getLocations()` supposed to do?

Comment: It just returns an ArrayList of Business objects, which have some location data

Comment: I assume it calls `execute` and then `get`, since you mention asynctask?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591878/updating-progress-dialog-in-activity-from-asynctask

Comment: Interesting - I just realized that ATask itself isn't an asynctask but calls another class which is. My main issue is that I want the progressdialog to start before ATask, and end after it returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814882/1851509) should be the definitive answer, at least for my situation.

Easy to implement, works even if you're calling asyncTasks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most working thing is to add the `Progress Dialog` to a real Async task(s) not some synchronous task. Your computer needs time to execute the Progress Dialog script and cannot, if the task is not in a thread or another Async event. Look other questions on SO and always there is a thread.