# Block scroll along with Expand/Collapse Collapsible Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I was using `Collapsible Toolbar` in my app. On activity launch *Collapsible Toolbar* is expanded state with scrolling enabled and its working well normally. But now I have a requirement to show a full screen error layout in case my API fails. In that case I have to collapsed toolbar with scrolling effect blocked.

Error Layout shows a Retry Button. On Retry I make API call again and if API gives success I have to again expand Toolbar and enable scrolling effect.

I was able to collapse toolbar with `setExpanded`(flag, animate) but in that case I am not able to block scrolling effect of Collapsible Toolbar while error layout is shown.

I need to provide a way to block as well as unblock scroll effect + Expand/Collapse Toolbar. Any help would be really appreciated.. !!!

Comment: can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a library [AppBarrr](https://github.com/Gitdefllo/AppBarrr.git) to lock the screen in expanded mode, based on my previous answer.

As I said, the height of the `Toolbar` is the key: the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` will collapse until the `Toolbar`'s height and will expand until the `AppBarLayout`'s height.

With this library, you must set two layouts as the `Toolbar` and your Expanded Layout (used to lock the screen and the scroll), it will create a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and inflate these layouts inside.

You can declare the animations duration, the color of the inner `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, the collapsed/expanded title's style, even the height of the locked layout... You could also hide the Expanded Layout if you click outside it. It can support `NestedScrollView` and `ScrollView` inside the Expanded Layout. [The documentation](https://github.com/Gitdefllo/AppBarrr/blob/master/DOCS.md) and a sample app are available on Github.

---

For those who don't want to use the library, [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41296398/4) shows the way to do it.  Here's the output of the previous answer:

[image: Prevent toolbar to expand with custom error layout]

Basically, this is the same concept, but no need to write a full class, with the lib you just need to have a simple widget in xml and that's it!

---

Feel free to use, fork or test. Hope it will be useful ;)

Comment: Hi Fllo, I appreciate your help. Can you please provide full code. Please upload code to git.

Comment: Your code is not showing how to enable back scrolling after we expand toolbar again. Can you please share code snippet for that too.

Answer (score 2):

Make your error layout such that it will overlap Collapsible Toolbar. Also set `android:clickable="true"` to your error layout.

When you set visibility to your error layout, set Toolbar scrolling accordingly.

```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#f3f3f3"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >
<!-- Add your other layout including Collapsible Toolbar here.-->

<RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/errorLayout"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) to communicate the error and a [ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841803/best-way-to-show-a-loading-spinner) (spinner) to show you are doing stuff, you can block user input while your app is doing it's thing.

Comment: My requirement states to use a error layout instead. Thats why I cannot use alert dialog here.

Comment: Can you talk this over with the client maybe? AlertDialog is made for stuff like this, and creating something else goes against the Android experience. (it never stopped one from trying something else tho)

Comment: Alert Dialog is not required as it would dismiss and screen will be shown blank. We need a error layout instead with a retry button to hit API again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that you can apply is just use the property

**android:visibility="gone"** 
for the content that you don't want to show and just make your *error layout* visible by using property **android:visibility="visible"**

place the error layout at the bottom of your parent layout

once the contents are not visible on screen and error layout is just visible you will achieve the desired result that you want. Hope this helps you.

Comment: but scrolling is not getting disabled in this case also. I am able to Expand/Collapse Collapsible toolbar in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the interface and call its methods when to enable or disable the collapsing effect.

```
public interface AppbarRequestListener {
    void unlockAppBarOpen();

    void lockAppBarClosed();
}

 @Override
    public void unlockAppBarOpen() {
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, false);
        appBarLayout.setActivated(true);
        setAppBarDragging(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void lockAppBarClosed() {
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, false);
        appBarLayout.setActivated(false);
        setAppBarDragging(false);

    }

    private void setAppBarDragging(final boolean isEnabled) {
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =
                (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
        behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
            @Override
            public boolean canDrag(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
                return isEnabled;
            }
        });
        params.setBehavior(behavior);
    }
```

Comment: animation stops working when calling `setAppBarDragging` and ` appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);` after that